# Fech data from a website using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I want to fech data from a website

for example , 
 data for value " **test1** ", i get from url " **www.reultssite.com?value=test1** "
 But the result page has ajax and results come after 30 sec as grid. Upto this time a "please wait "
 text will be shown in the page .

What i tried

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   client.DownloadFile(" www.reultssite.com?value=test1", @"D:\Out\a.htm");
}
```

But with the above code , the result **a.htm** has the "please wait"  text not the Grid. It do not have the data grid which comes after some seconds.

Is there a way to get the final data ?

Comment: Inspect the JS code on the page you are loading. Call the endpoint used by the AJAX to get the data used to populate the grid directly, instead of going through the page.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider thanks for the hint ,I will try it

Comment: What is the exact URL that you are targeting?  Honestly, I wouldn't use C# for this kind of task.  I think R, Python, or even Excel, would be infinitely better for this kind of thing.  Post back with the exact URL you want to fetch data from, and please describe exactly what you are trying to achieve.  Thanks.